# Delete previous cells form a particular row and create new cells in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uitableview, html-table

Here is the scenario:

User clicks on a button and can add new row in table.

Select a value from any of the row and few fields will be added in only that row. It works fine.

But problem is here: When user again selects any different rows it append the cells in rows, but I want to delete the previous cells and add new selected cells. I am not able to do that.

I tried with `deleteCell()` but did not find required solution. [here is the whole code](http://codepen.io/vorant/pen/PZVRBY?editors=1010). If any one could help please.

Another problem with code is when I run it the first time it does not count first row number.

```
for (i = 0; i < selectedvalue; i++) {
    var x = Row.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML = "<td><select><option value=3>3</option><option value=4>4</option><option value=5>5</option><option value=6>6</option></select></td> </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeZrov?editors=1010

```
jQuery('#myTable tr').eq(rownum).find("td:gt(3)").remove();
```

Comment: it dont work offline on my computer. can you please tell where to add this line.

Comment: Checkout the codepen link above;  `var firstRow = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[rownum];  
     alert('You clicked row ' + rownum);  
     jQuery('#myTable tr').eq(rownum).find("td:gt(3)").remove();`

Comment: Offline does not work because you have jQuery from CDN. Download jquery and place in one of your assets folder to work.